# SQL statement on a product database with multiple tables to extract image names

Tags: sql

I've got an ecommerce database where I'm trying to export all of the image names associated with a product into a csv file.

I'm writing it in php and running the script through the admin of the ecommerce system but I'm struggling to print out the results in a way I would like them.

The two tables involved are: `CubeCart_inventory` which contains the product information,  and `CubeCart_img_idx` which contains the associated images.

The tables are linked by a 'productid' so in the first table the product id is: `CubeCart_inventory.productId` and in the image table the id `CubeCart_img_idx.productId`.

Is there an SQL statement that I can use that puts all of the image names into a string which I can then use to write my csv on a product by product basis?

Example of the CubeCart_inventory table:

```
id | productId | productname  | price
____________________________________
1  |    1234   | Bag of Nails | £35
```

Example of the CubeCart_img_idx table

```
id | productId | img
____________________
 1 | 1234      | nails.jpg
 2 | 1234      | nails2.jpg
 3 | 5678      | otherproduct.jpg
 4 | 1234      | nails3.jpg
```

So what I would like is: `nails.jpg`, `nails2.jpg`, `nails3.jpg` all in one field in my CSV file because they are joined by the same `productId`

Comment: Is it MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? Solutions vary by product.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, looks like [GROUP_CONCAT](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/) is what you're looking for. For SQL Server, you can use [a combination of STUFF with a subquery](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/12/21/sql-server-comma-separated-values-csv-from-table-column-part-2/).